# look for match values in multiple columns and return the matched column head

Tags: python, pandas, match, multiple-columns

I'm trying to check which column (in 3 columns) contain the same value in column `min`, and return the column head of the match column. I can do it with `np.where`, then I need to manually enter the conditions and compare the columns, is there more elegant doing this?

An example of inputs:

```
 A    B   C   min    
 1    2   3   1      
 2    3   6   6      
 2    2   1   2
```

An example of outputs:

```
 A    B   C   min    which_col
 1    2   3   1      A
 2    3   6   6      C
 2    2   1   2      AB
```

I can use:

```
np.where(df['min']==df['A'], 'A', np.where(df['min']==df['B'], 'B')....)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**My Proposed Solution**

```
dd = df.drop('min', 1)
df.assign(which_col=dd.eq(df['min'], 0).dot(dd.columns))

   A  B  C  min which_col
0  1  2  3    1         A
1  2  3  6    6         C
2  2  2  1    2        AB
```

---

**Explanation**

I start by assigning a temp dataframe `dd` with all the columns less the `'min'` column.  I could've kept this all in one line, but I believe this facilitates readability.

```
dd = df.drop('min', 1)
```

Next, I compare the `'min'` column with `dd`.  But in order to compare each element of `df['min']` with each row of `dd` I need to pass the `axis=0` parameter to the `eq` method

```
dd.eq(df['min'], 0)

       A      B      C
0   True  False  False
1  False  False   True
2   True   True  False
```

If I use this result in a dot product, it will automatically be cast as int and therefore `False` becomes `0` and `True` becomes `1`.  When I use the `columns` of `dd` as the other operand, the sum aspect of the dot product automatically concatenates the strings within the columns where ever there is a match.

```
dd.eq(df['min'], 0).dot(dd.columns)

0     A
1     C
2    AB
dtype: object
```

Finally, I use `assign` to create a new copy of `df` with a new column containing the results.

Comment: @Kay in this case, `eq` is `pd.DataFrame.eq` which is a dataframe method.  The first argument is `self` which is the dataframe itself, and the second argument is `df['min']`.  So `a` is `dd` and `b` is `df['min']`.  However, when the the second argument is a series and not another dataframe, pandas aligns that series by the columns of the other datafame.  We need to change that to aligning with the index instead so we pass the argument `axis=0`.  If we had just done `dd == df['min']` we could not have passed `axis=0` so we use the method form instead.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Not sure if I made some mistake, but column`which_col` seems not created. The codes run without bug tho. Do you know why? Thanks!

Comment: @Kay, I use `assign` a lot because it's a non-invasive way to help.  When you run it, it doesn't mess up your existing dataframe by overwriting it.  `assign` produces a copy with a new column in it.  You have two choices, reassign to `df` by overwriting the variable name: `df = df.assign(which_col=dd.eq(df['min'], 0).dot(dd.columns))`.  Or, assign to a new column directly (what I avoid in my answers, but you're welcome to do) `df['which_col'] = dd.eq(df['min'], 0).dot(dd.columns)`

Comment: @piRSquared, it's a very elegant solution!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a liner.

```
In [138]: (df[list('ABC')].eq(df['min'], axis=0)
           .apply(lambda x: ''.join(x[x].index), axis=1))
Out[138]:
0      A
1      C
2    AB
dtype: object

In [139]: df['which_col'] = (df[list('ABC')].eq(df['min'], axis=0)
                             .apply(lambda x: ''.join(x[x].index), axis=1))

In [140]: df
Out[140]:
   A  B  C  min which_col
0  1  2  3    1         A
1  2  3  6    6         C
2  2  2  1    2        AB
```